# Spring autenticacion Directorio activo azure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

Tengo un proyecto en spring el cual debo modificar para que se autentique con el directorio activo de microsoft azure.
Mi pregunta es existe alguna forma de hacer el proceso sin necesidad de utilizar spring boot  o como migrar a spring boot para poder hacer este proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el la validacion por medio de un tutorial que me da azure https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/ el cual me da detallado el proceso.